# Out-of-proc COM factory CreateInstance returns E_UNEXPECTED

Tags: c++, com

I am trying to create instance of COM object using factory.

My server code is:

```
int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    HRESULT result = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    Factory factory;
    DWORD regID = 0;
    result = CoRegisterClassObject(CLSID_InterractionInterfaceFactory, (IClassFactory*) &factory, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE, &regID);

    MSG ms;
    while(GetMessage(&ms, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&ms);
        DispatchMessage(&ms);
    }

    CoRevokeClassObject(regID);

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

My client code is:

```
int main(int, char*[])
{
    HRESULT result;
    result = CoInitialize(NULL);

    IClassFactory* factory = NULL;

    result = CoGetClassObject(CLSID_InterractionInterfaceFactory, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, NULL, IID_IClassFactory, (void**)&factory);

    if (S_OK == result)
    {
        IInterractionInterface* iface = NULL;
        result = factory->CreateInstance(NULL, IID_InterractionInterface, (void**)&iface);
        **// HERE IT RETURNS E_UNEXPECTED**
    }

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

My QueryInterface method:

```
STDMETHODIMP InterractionInterface::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, LPVOID FAR * ppv)
{
    *ppv = NULL;

    if (riid == IID_IUnknown)
    {
        *ppv = (IUnknown*)this;
    }
    if (riid == IID_InterractionInterface)
    {
        *ppv = (IInterractionInterface*)this;
    }
    else
    {
        *ppv = NULL;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(*ppv)->AddRef() ;
    return S_OK;
}
```

I can not get what i am doing wrong. It enters to QueryInterface, the object is valid, reference counter is incremented, i am returning from Factory::CreateInstance(..., LPVOID* obj) S_OK, and obj is filled successfully, but client gets empty object and return code E_UNEXPECTED.

What i am doing wrong?

My interace is:

```
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_InterractionInterfaceFactory, 0x84d55f4a, 0xff3c, 0x43b2, 0xa1, 0xa3, 0x3a, 0xd3, 0xe9, 0x96, 0xc4, 0x26);

DEFINE_GUID(IID_InterractionInterface, 0xc191f3ac, 0x79e1, 0x4be3, 0xbb, 0x87, 0xac, 0x7a, 0xb8, 0x24, 0xd6, 0xb9);


class IInterractionInterface : public IUnknown
{
public:
    STDMETHOD (Test(int)) PURE;
};
```

Comment: The object is created on server side and then to make it available on client side, marshaling of the `IInterractionInterface` interface has to succeed... I suppose it is not the case.

Comment: Roman, and what i have to do to make this object marshable to client? I need to implement some interfacer or something else?

Comment: I don't think you are doing custom marshaling for `InterractionInterface` via implementing `IMarshal` intreface, so what matters then is where the interface is defined, whether type library exists and registered, is there proxy/stub library registered etc. The snippet you provided does not answer this.

Comment: I've added my interface to the question. I do not need any custom marshalling. What i have to do to implement proxy\stub mechanism?

Comment: Noone except you knows about your interface with such declaration. Hence, no marshaling could take place to establish communication between your client and server processed. Hence, the error. You need to put your interface into type library, which has to be registered with system/registry. Then you can have standard marshaling applied to your interface (additional constraints apply).

Comment: I've created proxy\stub dll and registered it in the system. And i've fount that when i am creating classFactory in client system process is trying to read CLSID of factory from system registry. Then when i am trying to call CreateInstance from factory it never trying to read registry and call proxy\stub dll. Why he want to send\receive my factory and does not trying to send\receive my object created in it?

Comment: I would better use ATL